# Need to scan email contents for spam before sending to users

Tags: php, spam, spamassassin

I have a PHP application which is used by clients to send emails to their customers. There is a page that lets client user build email templates to send to their customers.

I want to add a functionality called 'Spam check'. This will allow client users to check their email template pass spam filter or not.

I have spamassassin installed on the server. How do I use it to check spam contents in the email template before it is sent to the customers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can use Bayesian Spam Filter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering

For Background Knowledge

Bayesian probability  : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability
Bayesian inference    : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference

`PHP` Implementation It has been discussed here several times

[Combining individual probabilities in Naive Bayesian spam filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463983/combining-individual-probabilities-in-naive-bayesian-spam-filtering)

### Solution 2

Since you have `spamassassin installed` on your system you can

```
$fname = tempnam ( "/tmp", "sa" );
file_put_contents ( $fname, $message ); // Put the template in a file
/* Execute the system command and pass the file name to get spam count */
exec ( "/usr/bin/spamc -R < $fname", $score, $rr );
/* This will return score details in array format */
print_r ( $score );
```

You can now manipulate the score for spam filter